# Start and End sectors of partitions?

Tags: linux

How can i get the start and end sectors of the partitions of my harddisk via a bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `/sys/block/sda/sda1/start` and `/sys/block/sda/sda1/size`.

Replace `sda` and `sda1` with your device and partition.

Comment: It seems that these "start" and "size" properties are 512 bytes based, even though the partition is 4K in both physical and logical sectors. How come?

Comment: @MrCalvin Legacy reasons. Every tool coded to look at these expects 512 byte sectors for calculation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

That's a start:

```
sudo /sbin/fdisk  -l /dev/sdb | grep sdb[0-9]
```

Comment: What's the interrelation between blocks and sectors?

Comment: man fdisk : 
-u     When listing partition tables, give sizes in sectors instead of cylinders.